# Apache throws empty error, but site works

Tags: javascript, html, apache

I am building a home media server using Apache and PHP. I am getting two, possibly unrelated errors.
A particular page throws the error - but it is not the only page that does it, so the answer may be in some library code I wrote.

The error occurs when I select a directory of videos (or indeed books). The path to the desired directory is passed in a POST variable that uses a javascript onclick() routine to invoke.
When I do this Apache throws this sort of error:

```
[Tue Jun 23 12:12:40.767249 2020] [:error] [pid 12525] [client xxx.69.38.60:44662] videos/Fantasy, referer: https://media.myserver.com/videos.php
```

The associated code is this

```html
<div class="directory" style="position: absolute; top:165px; left:10px;" onclick="newpath('videos/Fantasy')">
    <img height="30" src="bitmaps/folder-video.png">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 3px; left:40px">Videos/Fantasy</div>
</div>
```

And the other bit is an input declaration and some javascript: viz:

```
<form id="ABCD" method="POST" action = "/videos.php">
<input type="hidden" id= "XYZ" name="filepath" value="">
</form>
<script>
function newpath(path)
    {
    document.getElementById("XYZ").value=path;
    document.getElementById("ABCD").submit(); 
    }
</script>
```

Now it may be unrelated, but the firefox debugging console is also throwing up an error I can't identify..

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list[Learn More] videos.php:1:60
```

Line 60 of that particular received HTML is the declaration of the hidden variable

Any help to push this to a resolution appreciated, as I said the code *works*, but I do not like unresolved errors that I do not understand.

Comment: videos.php:1:60 means check your line 1 and character 60

Comment: I can't see anything "exactly" wrong with the code you've presented, but it seems that there is more code, that might be broken.

Comment: Thanks Hassaan, I tidied up some of the javascript source and that one has vanished.

Answer (score 0):

I am so sorry. I must be going senile.

I had left some debugging code in the PHP

```
    {
    $root=$_POST['filepath'];
    error_log($_POST['filepath']);
    }
```

I didn't appreciate that using the error_log doesnt say where it comes from...